# Simple email forwarding server

Tags: c#, email, email-forwarding

I need to forward emails for a several domains to other email addresses. Previously I have used hMailServer on my Windows server to perform this forwarding function, but I am looking for something simpler that I can interface with from a .NET application.

Is there a simple email forwarding server I can easily manage from .NET? Spam filtering or email storage is not required.

Comment: Define what you mean with *manage*. What do you want to do more than sending emails?

Comment: @jgauffin, by manage I mean the CRUD of domains with corresponding forwarding addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used hMailServer but according to the documentation there's a [COM API](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.3/?page=com_objects) that looks like it would be automation compatible (since they've got VBScript samples) so you should be able to access this from .Net.

I'd suggest looking at the [Rule object](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.3/?page=com_object_rule) or the [forum](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/)

Comment: I knew about the COM API, but it feels...COMmy. Isn't there a simple forwarding server for .NET somewhere?

Comment: @FreshCode: Don't know I'm afraid. I'd suggest looking at codeproject.com to check if you can find an article about writing your own in some .Net language.